# Run fortran exe in java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, fortran

Respected sir/madam,

I have a fortran exe which takes a input file and produces output file by doing some manipulation on input file.I am able to run the command in linux terminal.(I think fortran compiler is availble in linux).Now please suggest how to run this fortran executable file using java(in Linux machine).

What i attempted is,

```
 String cmd="fortranExe arg1 arg2";
 //fortranExe=exe path
 //arg1,arg2 are arguments to fortran executable program
 Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

But i am not getting output.When i tried to run Linux commands such as ls,dir are giving output.Is anything required for running fortran code in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like this

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\PathToExe\\fortran.exe","param1","param2").start();
```

Got this from

[Java Programming: call an exe from Java and passing parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604698/java-programming-call-an-exe-from-java-and-passing-parameters)

More info on ProcessBuilder: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: Actually i want to run fortran 6s(i have downloaded from ftp://kratmos.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/eric/6S/)and able to run the code in linux  manchine.Actually the command is: sixsV1.1 <InputFileName.txt >OutputFileName.txt.

Answer (score 1):

No, if it's a reqular binary for the platform you are running your JVM on, it shouldn't matter.

How are you running the binary, when you run from console?

Once the process was generated successfully, you can read its stdout like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
br.close();
```

If there was any runtime problem executing the process, e.g. no permission to run the binary etc., the process.exitValue() will return 127.

EDIT: 
seeing the other comments, I can see that you are using redirected in/output to your binary.

So in fact there are no parameters, but you need to open InputFileName.txt and use the process.getOutputStream() Object to write to your process. No need to set OutputFilename.txt, because you read the output from the InputStream and if necessary can write it yourself to a file.

This answer explains it in detail:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3644288/435583

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6796053/435583

Cheers,

Comment: I have given 777 permissions to Folder.

Comment: what is the output when you run "file fortranExe" from the shell?

Comment: it generates output file.The command has 2 args.1 is inputfile path and second is outputfile.

Comment: Hi, I edited my original answer slightly due to the additional details you provided...

Comment: I have tried this also.i.e i have not given outfile path and sent the output stream to output file.But when i tried to print, the buffer is empty

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using Runtime,  a more **cleaner way** will be to use [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access). See specific example for [Fortran here](http://www.javaforge.com/wiki/66061).

You can even **call individual pieces like subroutines** of your Fortan program directly from Java. JNA is **generally used** to invoke C/C++ programs and are generally suited for this type of use cases and I guess yours use case fits well here.

Comment: The fortran code is freely available and more over it is tested properly.so i want to use that fortran code without changing from java.

Comment: Thats file. Does this approach needs the Fortran code to be changed ?

Comment: no sir,Actually i compiled the code and able to get binary file which can be executed in linux terminal.

Comment: Right. JNA just needs that binary file. By the way did you get a chance to go through the link I mentioned ?

Comment: As it is binary file,i dont know how to call

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13037/discussion-between-suresh-kumar-and-santosh)