# Clojure Execute Shell Command - dump postgres

Tags: clojure

I am trying to execute this code:

```
(define dump-db []
 (. (Runtime/getRuntime) exec "pg_dump database-name | gzip -c > db-name.out.gz"))
```

But the db-name.out.gz file does not is created.
Other commands like "ls" or "touch foo.txt" were successfully executed.

Any help?

Comment: What happens if you don't pipe to gzip? "pg_dump database-name  > db-name.out" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate [(Java) File redirection (both ways) within Runtime.exec?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795924/java-file-redirection-both-ways-within-runtime-exec).

Comment: Barth, nothing happens.

Comment: @elf Please check the contents of the output stream from `Process.getOutputStream()` that  `Runtime.exec()` returns. The result from the command should be there. AFAICT stdout and stdin redirection don't work when using `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.exec()`.

Comment: piping and redirecting are "shell features". if in doubt you can "always" use `sh -c 'mycommand | shellfeature > pipetofile'`

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for now:

```
(defn foo [line]
(with-open [wrtr (writer "/tmp/test.txt" :append true)]
  (.write wrtr (str line "\n"))))

(->> (.. Runtime getRuntime (exec "pg_dump db-name") getInputStream)
     java.io.InputStreamReader.
     java.io.BufferedReader.
     line-seq
     (map foo))
```